# SQL Partition Data by Date Range ignoring date gaps and weekends

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, partitioning, partition

Thank you in advance for your patience, and help!

I am trying to partition my data in a way that displays date ranges.

[IMAGE: Data Set - Current Results - Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oR4W.jpg)

In the image you can see what my data set looks like. The results I'm currently getting. As well as, the results I would like to get.

Here is the code that I've got that is getting me my current results. I'm struggling understanding PARTITION.

**Edit** I can bring Saturday and Sunday back in, if the data is necessary to have all 365 consecutive days. I'm simply removing it from the Data Source in the WHERE clause.

```
--DELETE TEMP TABLE USED TO STORE CONSECUTIVE ABSENCES
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #StuConsecAtt;

--CREATE TEMP TABLE THAT STORES CONSECUTIVE ABSENCE DATE RANGES
CREATE TABLE #StuConsecAtt(
SIS_NUMBER INT,
ABS_FROM DATE,
ABS_TO DATE
);

--INSERT CONSECUTIVE ABSENCE DATA NEW TABLE
WITH stuAtt
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY SIS_NUMBER ORDER BY ABS_DATE
                ), ABS_DATE) AS grp
    FROM #stuCalAtt
    )

INSERT INTO #StuConsecAtt
(ABS_FROM, ABS_TO, SIS_NUMBER)

SELECT min(ABS_DATE) AS [From]
    ,max(ABS_DATE) AS [To]
--    ,[ABS_REASON]
    ,SIS_NUMBER
FROM stuATT
GROUP BY SIS_NUMBER
    ,grp
ORDER BY [From];

SELECT * FROM #StuConsecAtt
WHERE ABS_TO > ABS_FROM;
```

***EDIT BELOW***
**DATA**
Looking at the data I'm trying to put consecutive days with ABSENT_DATE = Y in a single group. Below 10/4 through 10/11 are consecutive (but the weekends would be ABSENT_DAY = N) so I removed the weekends. No because 10/4 through 10/11 are grouped together (consecutive in the dataset), all with ABSENT_DAY = Y, I would like to group them so I can get the outcome range of 10/4-10/11. Just like the following range would be 10/18 - 10/19. Where the weekend gap is, is cause the issue.

```
SIS_NUMBER CALENDAR_DATE WEEK_DAY  ABS_DATE   SCHOOL_DAY ABSENT_DAY
641861     2017-10-03    Tuesday   NULL       Y           N
641861     2017-10-04    Wednesday 2017-10-04 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-05    Thursday  2017-10-05 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-06    Friday    2017-10-06 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-09    Monday    2017-10-09 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-10    Tuesday   2017-10-10 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-11    Wednesday 2017-10-11 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-12    Thursday  NULL       N           N
641861     2017-10-13    Friday    NULL       N           N
641861     2017-10-16    Monday    NULL       Y           N
641861     2017-10-17    Tuesday   NULL       Y           N
641861     2017-10-18    Wednesday 2017-10-18 Y           Y
641861     2017-10-19    Thursday  2017-10-19 Y           Y
```

**CURRENT RESULTS**

```
SIS_NUMBER FROM_DATE    TO_DATE
641861     2017-10-04   2017-10-06
641861     2017-10-09   2017-10-11
641861     2017-10-18   2017-10-19
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

```
SIS_NUMBER FROM_DATE    TO_DATE
641861     2017-10-04   2017-10-11
641861     2017-10-18   2017-10-19
```

Comment: Please post text of data, results, and desired results.  Explain displays date ranges.

Comment: I've updated, and hope the explanation of the date range is useful. Thank you for looking paparazzo!